# How to ensure Cloud-Init runs exactly once and once only?

Tags: cloud-init

As far as I can see, `cloud-init` runs every time the config changes. Not just the very first time the system boots, but every time the provided configuration changes. This makes somewhat sense, as I guess it's hard to define the "first time" (the cloned VM already ran before being frozen and used as template, so it's never really the first time). However, I've—from time to time, quite rarely, but still—found that `cloud-init` re-runs on already provisioned system when they reboot.

Some steps, however, seem to screw up the setup when `cloud-init` is run on a fully configured system. For example, if it is run one more time after the initial setup and `cloud-init` sets some configuration to value `X`, but you had it manually overridden afterwards to `Y` and now `cloud-init` re-runs to set it back to `X`. Or, have the system recreate your SSH host keys.

I've thus found it quite useful to manually run:

```sh
sudo touch /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled
```

...after the initial setup to prevent it from ever running `cloud-init` again. (In cases, where `cloud-init` really is only used for an initial "clone & set IPs/hostname" kind of configurations.)

But is there any way to automate this? Like adding some parameter to the `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` that disabled itself after the next run?

Comment: It *always* runs, unless you disable it. Even if you don't have per-boot config, the per-instance config can be persuaded to run again. What you're doing is, IMHO, the right thing to do (or modifying the boot command line). Just put this in you `/etc/rc.d` or similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Different `cloud-init` modules have different frequencies: `once-per-instance` and `always`. You can check attribute `Module frequency` for each module in the [Modules documentation](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html). For example, `bootcmd` runs on every boot but `runcmd` only on the first boot. The frequencies can be overridden in a cloud-config file modules lists - `cloud_init_modules`, `cloud_config_modules` and `cloud_final_modules`. Example override:

```
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]
```